# MYSQL Update column in Case

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, sql-insert

I want to set object_type Elite, Premium or Regular by price value, how i can update object_type column in my DB?

My SQL request looks like:

```
select price_per_m2, 
    (
    CASE 
        WHEN price_per_m2 > 500000 THEN 'Elite'
        WHEN price_per_m2 > 200000 && price_per_m2 < 499999  THEN 'Premium'
        ELSE 'Regular'
    END) AS object_type
 from new_housing;
```

Comment: With an update statement?

Comment: With Update in loop of all my items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With condition

```
UPDATE new_housing
SET object_type = CASE WHEN price_per_m2 > 500000 THEN 'Elite'
                       WHEN price_per_m2 > 200000 && price_per_m2 < 499999  THEN 'Premium'
                       ELSE 'Regular' END
WHERE price_per_m2;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the following query:

```
UPDATE new_housing
SET object_type = CASE WHEN price_per_m2 > 500000 THEN 'Elite'
                       WHEN price_per_m2 > 200000 && price_per_m2 < 499999  THEN 'Premium'
                       ELSE 'Regular' END
WHERE <some condition>;
```